# Как загрузить в windows forms изображение в форму pictureBox?

Tags: c#

у меня есть папка, в которой хранятся изображения.Мне нужно чтобы если условие выполняется, программа выводила в форму pictureBox одно из этих изображений.Как такое сделать?(c#)

Comment: у pictureBox есть метод Load - передайте в качестве параметра этому методу вашу картинку и все

Comment: Что нужно сделать, чтобы схлопотать бан во всех поисковиках?

Comment: что вы имеете ввиду?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если условие верное, то ищем файлы из папки (читаем [это](http://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.io.directory.aspx)), и загружаем выбранные в PictureBox (читаем [это](http://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.windows.forms.picturebox.aspx) и [это](http://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.drawing.bitmap.aspx))

Comment: а какой метод для поиска использовать?

Comment: В ссылке на класс Directory есть пример использования. Думаю разберётесь

Comment: нашел это Picturebox.Image = Image.FromFile("#")

Comment: ой еще вопрос...а как сделать так чтобы взять изображение из ресурсов?

Comment: Читаем последнюю ссылку про битмапы и смотрим метод `FromResource`

Comment: нашел pictureBox2.Image = Properties.Resources.file; где file имя изображения в ресурсах программы

Answer (score 1):

```
        if (/*ваше условие*/)
        {
            System.IO.FileStream fs = new System.IO.FileStream(@"Путь к файлу", System.IO.FileMode.Open);
            System.Drawing.Image img = System.Drawing.Image.FromStream(fs);
            fs.Close();
            pictureBox1.Image = img;
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Так лучше

```
pictureBox.Image = Properties.Resources.картинка;
```